# Files informations on unix-based file systems

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

When I create a new file (eg. touch file.txt) its size equals to 0B.
I'm wondering where are its informations (size, last modify date, owner name, file name) stored.
These informations are stored on hd and are managed by kernel, of course, but I'd love to know something more about them:
Where and how I may get them, using a programming language as C, for example, and how I may change them.
Are these informations changeable, simply using a programming language, or maybe kernel avoids this operations?

I'm working on Unix based file systems, and I'm asking informations especially about this fs.

Comment: Take a look at Unix Systems Programming, you will find low level functions for these operations

Answer (score 3):

On unix system, they're traditionally stored in the metadata part of a file representation called an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)

You can fetch this information with the [stat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/stat.html) call, see [these](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) fields, you can change the owner and permissions with [chown](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/chown.html)() and [chmod](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/chmod.html)()

Answer (score 2):

This information is retrievable using the `stat()` function (and others in its family). Where it's stored is up to the specific file system and for what should be obvious reasons, you cannot change them unless you have raw access to the drive -- and that should be avoided unless you're ok with losing everything on that drive.

Comment: I understand that neither the kernel modifies values such as "size", but limits to read it from drive. This may be obvious, but I wanted a confirm to my thoughts. Thank you for the answer, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata such as owner, size and dates are usually stored in a structure called [index-node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (inode), which resides in the filesystem's superblock.